# Adding incrementing value to table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table DateDim in database northwind_warehouse. I need to add new int primary key column named 'DateID' in this table with incrementing value starting with 109574 and increasing on 1 every new row. How can i do this if i have 1000 rows in table?

Comment: Why do you care what value your identity starts with?

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand you have no primary key in this table now, so you could do this

```
alter table DateDim add DateID int not null identity (109574, 1)
alter table DateDim add constraint PK_DateDim_ID primary key (DateID)
```

[Click here to see it working](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1985aa18c7875cb057476321d99a1c18)

Comment: You would need to add (109574, 1) to the identity so it will start with the number they want it to start with.

Comment: @SeanLange Oops I looked over that, corrected the answer. Thanks for noticing